# What is alternative of platform.dist and platform.linux_distribution in python3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

It says [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html) both Platform.dist() and platform.linux_distribution has been **deprecated** in version 3.5 and will be **removed** in version 3.7 (Current version 3.6.5 with 3.7 in preview mode). and I can't find any way around on how to find/get linux distro name in python3!

Any way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a small search, I found it [here](https://pypi.org/project/distro/#description.) and it can be installed with `pip install distro`. 
Then `import distro` instead of the `import platform`.

```
import distro 
print(distro.linux_distribution())
```

Output:

```
('Ubuntu', '18.04', 'Bionic Beaver')
```

I’ve tested in python versions 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and it’s working perfectly.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please try and always include a small code example or text-excerpt if you provide external links. In this case, you could include a quick demonstration how the module you found provides the desired information, and what the information looks like.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `import distro

print(distro.linux_distribution())  ('Ubuntu', '18.04', 'Bionic Beaver')`

Comment: Yes, that is a good example. You could edit your question again and include it their for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't search this a lot, but if you want the version informations, an easy way, maybe what python's `platform.linux_distribution` did anyway, would be to read files

`/etc/*-release`
or
`/proc/version`

and see what you can get from them. ^^'

So long that it's not in a performance-wise critical section of the code.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Okay.. I have some time to kill.. If I don't find any other solution, I will try this and mark yours as correct answer. (If works)

Comment: And of course you can encapsulate it in your own platform.distribution module if you want to stay compatible with old code when upgrading to python 7. ;) (Might need to give a different name and do some search/replace over the files tho.)

Answer (score 0):

This pip package solves it. [Not limited to python 3.7 issue]

https://github.com/nir0s/distro